# Concatenate Each cell in column A with Column B in Python DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

Need help in concatenating each row of a column with other column of a dataframe

Input:
[image]

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) in list comprehension:

```
from  itertools import product

L = [''.join(x) for x in product(df['Col1'], df['Col2'])]
#alternative
L = [a + b for a, b in product(df['Col1'], df['Col2'])]
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col3':L})
print (df)
 Col3
0  AE
1  AF
2  AG
3  BE
4  BF
5  BG
6  CE
7  CF
8  CG
```

Or cross join solution with helper column `a`:

```
df1 = df.assign(a=1)
df1 = df1.merge(df1, on='a')

df = (df1['Col1_x'] + df1['Col2_y']).to_frame('Col3')
```

Answer (score -1):

**Remark:** it's easier to help if you copy the code for creating the input rather than images such as:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],['E', 'F', 'G', 'H']], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

**Solution:** least effort is the itertools library

```
from itertools import product

lst1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] 
lst2 = ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H']

reslst = list(product(lst1, lst2))
```

or as dataframe series:

```
reslst = list(product(df['col1'].values, df['col2'].values))

print(reslst)
```

**Note:** as you know the result is a list which is `n**2` long and hence can not be assigned to the original dataframe.